# Entropy value for different sets of data

Tags: data-mining, entropy

I am trying to compute the entropy for different sets of data and then compare the obtained values.

The idea is that the sets of data may change their size, I might have sets sizes ranging from 10 to 200 values.

In order to compare the entropy level obtained for them should I first normalize it with respect to the set sizes (basically just divide it by the number of data values within each set)?

How should I proceed in this matter?

Comment: Are you wanting to calculate some *empirical estimate* of the entropy of a source?

Comment: the thing is that I have to analyse some MFL data(Magnetic Flux Leakage) and I want to analyse batches of values which present some characteristics and one of the measures at which I thought was the entropy measure. I normalized all the values within 0 and 1 so that they can be considered as probabilities and then I applied the entropy measure. The problem is that those batches may have different sizes and I'm not sure if I can compare the entropy values for batches with different sizes.